# Convert getdate() to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm on Microsoft SQL Server
I try to convert a get date to this format :

`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ`

I have try to using the function CONVERT this date on varchar like this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 127))
```

For today when I execute this request the result is:

```
2018-06-22T15:18:13.463
```

How can I have this `getdate()` on the format `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ` ?

Thanks

Comment: The presentation format of your date(time) should be done in your presentation layer, ideally, not in your SQL. Pass a `datetime(2)` datatype back to your presentation layer, and then do the formatting there. Especially if you're looking to store that format.

Comment: Yes I want to stock this date on a variable like @date

Comment: Quite simpy, don't. Use a proper datetime datatype, not a `varchar`.

Comment: @dutycorpse Larnu talks of giving the date as a date()-data-type to your application(in c#, java, whatever) and then perform a operation there to display it the way you like

Comment: I need to stock this value on varchar because I add this value on json file

Comment: `GETDATE()` returns a `datetime` which doesn't have timezone information. You could have a look at `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`, but that has a much higher precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can change the format is by converting the date to a string with something like what you have...

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), getdate(), 127)
```

What folks generally do is store and manipulate the date in native date format, then convert it to a presentation format before export or client retrieval (like through a website, web service, thick client, etc.)

Comment: I have the same result whit this request

Comment: Yup, hence that first remark, "The only way you can change the format is by converting the date to a string with something like what you have."

Comment: It's impossible to have this format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ ?

Comment: Correct, it is impossible to have GetDate() return you a native datetime type (i.e., time, datetime, datetime2, smalldatetime, or datetimeoffset) that displays in that format. To get the format you're asking in SQL Server, you'll need to cast to a character type (e.g., varchar, nvarchar, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

```
        -- ================================================
        -- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
        -- Create Scalar Function (New Menu).SQL
        --
        -- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
        -- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
        -- values below.
        --
        -- This block of comments will not be included in
        -- the definition of the function.
        -- ================================================
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
        -- =============================================
        -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
        -- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
        -- Description: <Description, ,>
        -- =============================================
        CREATE FUNCTION getdateJSON()
        RETURNS nvarchar(50)
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @ret as nvarchar(50);

            select @ret = CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 127));

            Return @ret;

        END
        GO
```

then

```
          select dbo.getdateJSON();
```

Comment: This is just op's code wrapped in a function. You're also mingling datatypes badly.

Comment: I'll take your criticisms on board - it was hard to see what he wanted to do exactly - I don't know why I mixed those data types.  My idea was for him not to have to repeat his code over-and-over - maybe it should have just been a comment.